# Java Websocket Emit Array

Tags: java, android, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I am having trouble sending a JSONArray through socket.io in JAVA.

With the function below i am trying to authorize the user with his username and token.

```
public static void authorize()
    {
        HashMap<String, String> user = Database.getUser();

        JSONArray req = new JSONArray();

        try {
            JSONObject reqObj = new JSONObject();
            reqObj.put("username", user.get("username"));
            req.put( reqObj );
            reqObj = new JSONObject();
            reqObj.put("usertoken", user.get("usertoken"));
            req.put( reqObj );
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("WebsocketFunctions", "Authorize: " + req.toString());
        Socket.emit("authorize", req);
    }
```

This is the Log.d("WebsocketFunctions") output:

> Authorize: [{"username":"admin"},{"usertoken":"45345980983450983"}]

But on my node server i only get:

> debug - websocket writing 1:: {username : 'admin'}

What i need is not only the username, but also the usertoken. Somehow the usertoken is not send to the server.

This is my node authorize function:

```
authorize: function(socket, data)
        {
            console.log('Authorize');
            console.log(data);
        },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know where is the problem but one thing I'm sure about is that you can do this without `JSONArray`. I do this and this works:

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.putOpt("username", user.get("username"));
obj.putOpt("usertoken", user.get("usertoken"));
socket.emit("authorize", obj);
```

If you want to send `int` or `double` then use this:

```
obj.put("key", value);
```

You can access it in socket.io server this way:

```
socket.on("authorize", function(data) {
   var user = data.username;
   var token = data.usertoken;
})
```

Comment: I use https://github.com/koush/android-websockets as websocket. But it  cannot handle a JSONObject as param. Only a JSONArray

Comment: I see. I thought you were using "https://github.com/Gottox/socket.io-java-client"